# how can I write a scss use vw unit in mobile and use px in pc

Tags: html, css, sass

I try something like this, but not working.

```
@media (min-width:750px) {
    @function pxvw($val){
        @return $val * 1px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:750px) {
    @function pxvw($val){
        @return $val * 1vw;
    }
}
.block{
    height: pxvw(30);
    width: pxvw(30);
}
```

Is there any solution to make this work？

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.